# Node modules are sometimes installed in program files and sometimes in APPDATA

Tags: node.js, npm

I have read quite a lot on this topic here on SO, but I still can't figure it out.

Why sometimes node modules are installed in `c:\program files(x86)\nodejs` and sometimes in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm`?

I understand the permission problem where a `cmd` that is not an administrator, can't install files in program files, but it doesn't explain several modules that are installed in `c:\program files`

Thanks